# How can I extend test class coverage to exception (`catch`) blocks?

Tags: apex, unit-test, exception, failing-tests

1. I am calling a function (that is defined in some other helper class) in a controller that will populate a list.
2. Due to some problem in that other helper class, it is not returning the data, it just returns null (it just does a query depending on some parameters) instead of the data/list I want.
3. I have even created and inserted an object instance with ALL the details that the helper class function needs, but it still returns null.

Please take a look here : [image: my code block].

The `transactionWrap` list is empty (I am unable to populate it).

As far as I know, that ought to throw an exception.

However, should it not stop execution at that point? Why does it continue upto the `if(SuccessTransactionList)` block?

Comment: I don't think there is any exception being caught in your for loop even when transactionWrap is empty, that is why it is not going into the catch block. Please use a scenerio in your test class which would actually result in an exception.

Comment: Could you give an example of such a scenario, please? The best I can think of right now is making `bIsblockEntry` to true, so it stops there.

Comment: An empty list will not throw an error. However making bisblockentey null will as your current use dereferences to to see if it is true or false